# Current booster DC-DC 300mA - 900mA

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have a source of power which can provide up to 300 mA at 1.5 V DC, however I would like to power a circuit which uses 900 mA at .5 V DC. What would be the easiest way to do this? If it was AC I could just use a transformer.

Comment: Your power available (.3A*1.5V) and power out (.9A*.5V) are the same (0.45 watts) -- no conversion is going to be 100% efficient, so you are going to have to adjust something.

Comment: Please provide more detail. You say "if t was AC". Does this mean it COULD be AC? Why 1.5V? Why 0.5V? A buck converter with synchronous rectification might exceed 90% wit care. More information = better answers

Comment: It is DC. My main problem was not knowing where to look for this, but using a buck convertor with synchronous rectification looks like it should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible.  You have only 450 mW available, and want to get 450 mW out.  No such current/voltage conversion process (not even a transformer if it were AC) is 100% efficient.

At such low voltages, every possible trick will be required just to get reasonable efficiencies.  You have very little room for any voltage drops on switching elements, resistance of inductors, and diodes.  Synchronous rectification will be essential.  But that's only for reasonable efficiencies.  Again, what you are trying to do is impossible.

Comment: What range of efficiency do you think would be reasonably achievable?

Comment: @W5VO: I haven't done a power supply with both voltages so low before, so I'm not sure.  I'd be really really impressed if someone got this to 90% at any reasonable cost.  80% would be quite good, I think.  This design needs to be done by someone that really knows what they are doing, which means noone that has to ask here for help.  Again, I'm not expert in this regime.  Maybe someone who has worked with such low voltages can chime in.

Comment: Say the input voltage was 5V, what would the basic design of the convertor be?

Comment: @cml: 5V in makes is a little easier, but the topology is the same either way.  You still need synchronous rectification due to the low output voltage else the efficiency will be under 50%.

Comment: Okay... I have very little experience with power supplies, is there someplace I could look for how to go about designing something like this?

Comment: First step is to tell us what you are trying to achieve. You have extremely good resources available right here - but the question needs to provide enough detail to slve your real problem.

Comment: @cml: What you apparently want is known as a buck converter, but as said before, it will have to include synchronous rectification.  There must be lots of stuff to find on the net with those keywords.